# Rails3 using i18n strings in model file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

In an application, strings need to be generated in a user's language and then passed onto another server/application.  Thus the model can identify

```
  def user_language
    self.user.idioma.code.downcase
  end
```

but then generating a string based on that language and reading the locale's yaml file is the challenge:

```
  def description
    user_language.products.name
  end
```

I realize that the model has no idea to go and look-up a locale file.  How can that be invoked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simpler (and as I expected, rather succinct)

```
  def description
    I18n.t('products.name', :locale => user_language)
  end
```

Note the capital 'I' in I18n. I stayed stuck on this for quite a while.  Most references I've seen use 1st character lowercase => i18n, but that generates an

> undefined local variable or method `i18n'